# Dc.Js Row Chart removing empty bins

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I have two row charts with crossfilter and Dc.Js.

You can see my example here: http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/363734495adb480201ee4ca3b676c5db

I want to remove the empty bins follwing this https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins. I want to remove the empty bins of my district name chart. How I can adapt my code? This is my fork with my attemp to remove the empty bins of my district Chart... Thanks for the help!

http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/a3aabaa6f846cdcd5760c3c7885e27c0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
var group = allDim.group(districtgroup);
```

You are passing a group as your group key function when you construct another group, but a function is expected. That's why crossfilter keeps complaining that `key` (the group argument) is not a function.

You already have a group which I think you intended to use:

```
var districtgroup = districtDIM.group();
```

If you simply pass that through `remove_empty_bins` everything seems to work?

```
var filtered_group = remove_empty_bins(districtgroup)
```

[Fork of your fiddle.](http://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/0f7a4ccf786fb4ae38cf7512d3e8a6e5)

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your explanation!